# How to code for multiple ‘or’ conditions in an ifelse command for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am relatively new to R and I am attempting to add a column to a dataframe (called dGroup) which is conditional on the names specified in an existing column (Species) in the dataframe.
There are a number of species that will belong to each of three groups to be specified in the dGroup column. These are “Mus (Mouse)” or “Cerc (Possum)” should generate a “SM” in the dGroup column, “Tri (Brush tail)” or “Thyl (Wallaby)” or “Mac (Bennetts)” should generate a “MM” in the dGroup column, and “Mac (Bennetts)” should generate a “LM” in the dGroup column.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
|Record|Species|        dGroup|
|------|--------|-------|
|1|     Mus (Mouse)|
|2|     Cerc (Possum)|
|3|     Tri (Brush tail)
|4|     Thyl (Wallaby)
|5|     Vom (Wombat)
|6|     Mac (Bennetts)
```

The code I am using is as follows:
#import csv ensuring character strings remain

```
    df <- read.csv(file = 'SH.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#add a new column to the dataframe called dGroup

    df['dGroup']<-NA

#test with a single species note: this code words

    df$dGroup = ifelse(df$Species == "Mus (Mouse)","SM", "NA")

#test combine two species in an ‘or’ condition note: this code does not work

    df$dGroup = ifelse(df$Species == "Mus (Mouse)"||df$Species=="Cerc ( Possum)"){"SM", “NA”)}
```

I receive the following error:
Error: unexpected '{' in
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

You can use the `case_when` command when generating (`mutate`) the new variable (`dGroup`) in your dataframe

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(dGroup = case_when(Species == "Mus (Mouse)" ~ "SM",
                            Species == "Cerc (Possum)" ~ "SM"))
```

You can continue to fill in the conditions for the other species. here is a nice resource on `case_when`: https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/case-when-r/

Comment: Sincere thanks, as suggested case_when and mutate are a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
df %>% mutate(dGroup = ifelse(Species %in% c("Mus (Mouse)", "Cerc (Possum)"), "SM", NA))
```

Comment: Many thanks, the suggested code works however my dataframe may have contained too many rows for this solution because after running it I received the following '[ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 8910 rows ]'.